# Calculating sum of the scores of similar ids

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a web site in asp.net with C# language.

I have 9 lists. Each lists have 2 columns : ID with int type, and Value with int16 type. ID is unique.

1. I want to calculate score of each ID in each list with a special formula. For instance, you think this is the result after calculating all scores:

id    ,    list number  ,     value     ,   score

100  ,         1       ,       2       ,     10

300   ,         1      ,      2       ,      9

200   ,        1      ,      4       ,      11

100   ,         2      ,       3       ,      10.5

200   ,        2       ,       3       ,      10

...

2. I want to calculate sum of the scores of each id. I mean, the final score of id number 100 in my example is: 10+10.5+....

What do you suggest for me to do this? My idea for first stage is to create a list and store id, list name, value, and score in it(like the above table), but I don't know how to do stage 2.

I would be grateful if you kindly help me.
Thanks a lot

Comment: show us your code, and what you have tried so far. with that being said, i would recommend using `System.Linq`, will make your life much easier.

Comment: I am writing an algorithm which includes over 500 lines and I used different functions and classes which are dependent. So, it takes your time to go through them. I tried to explain what I want to do in this part in the best way i could. I know it's not so clear,but i couldn't explain in a better way. I would be grateful if you kindly help me. Can you explain how to use linq for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented console app code for your requirement.
Here is the working code.

First It performs grouping by ID, then sums up scores in each group of ID
Final result is Dictionary of ID & sum of scores for This ID.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var records = new[] {
                                new Records{ID=100,ListNum=1,Value=2,Score=10},
                                new Records{ID=300,ListNum=1,Value=2,Score=9},
                                new Records{ID=200,ListNum=1,Value=4,Score=11},
                                new Records{ID=100,ListNum=2,Value=3,Score=10.5},
                                new Records{ID=200,ListNum=2,Value=3,Score=10}
                               };
            var idScoreSumDictionary = records
                             .GroupBy(rec => rec.ID)
                             .ToDictionary(
                                 rec => rec.Key, 
                                 rec => rec.Sum(x => x.Score)
                             );
           foreach (var item in idScoreSumDictionary)
           {
                Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}",item.Key);
                Console.WriteLine("Its Score Sum: {0}",item.Value);
           }
        }
    }

    class Records
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ListNum { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public double Score { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really helped me.
I was working on what you said. I got the result until you said, but now, I want to use these numbers, I mean I want to use these ids and sum of each ids in an array, for instance,, for next stage. I couldn't do that.
I don't know how to use data in idScoreSumDictionary. Can you help me what to do for this problem?
Best Regards.

Comment: Thanks. Finally I could solve it after lots of attempt.

Comment: I did no understand the phrase "I mean I want to use these ids and sum of each ids in an array" and i have edited my answer, hope it will help.